# Why main scrollbar color doesn't change in Firefox?

Tags: css, reactjs, firefox, sass, scrollbar

I have a problem with styling the scrollbar for Firefox using **var(...)**.

As we can see code below:

```
* {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: var(--sb-bgc);
  }

  scrollbar-color: var(--sb-bgc) transparent;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

everything should work fine but the **main scrollbar** in **Firefox** is not reading property in **var(...)**. Deep in site, **other scrollbars** in Firefox **work correctly**...

If I use **color directly**, such as **red** or some variable like **$someVaraible** everything works fine. The problem is only when I use **var(...)** - I need it to switch colors between light and dark themes.

**EDIT:**

I'm using Windows 10.

Add `data-theme="light"` or `data-theme="dark"` to the `body` tag.
In the `body` tag add some `div` with class `root`.

In some style.scss file copy (this doesn't' work on main page because of var(...) property:

```
.root {
  height: 200vh;
}

$lightBlueColor: #2ac6c7;
$darkBlueColor: #17b9ba;

[data-theme='light'] {
  --sb-bgc: #{$lightBlueColor};
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
  --sb-bgc: #{$darkBlueColor};
}

* {
  &::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background-color: transparent;
  }

  &::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: var(--sb-bgc);
  }

  scrollbar-color: var(--sb-bgc) transparent;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

As I mentioned before the problem is using **var(...)**. If I use `$lightBlueColor` or `#2ac6c7` directly in `scrollbar-color` there is no problem and everything works fine. When I'm using **var(...)** nothing happened.

So one more time. **I know** that I can write the code as below and it will work:

```
...
scrollbar-color: $lightBlueColor transparent;
...
```

or

```
...
scrollbar-color: #2ac6c7 transparent;
...
```

**But it is no solution for me** because the color needs to be changed when the theme change. And because of that, I need a working **var(...)** property solution.

Comment: Translating to pure CSS and with the body at 200vh high the scroll bar in FF is fine (I defined the CSS variable in :root). I'm on Windows10. What system are you testing on and could you create a runnable snippet that shows the problem because I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @AHaworth I edit my post with more explanation.

Comment: I think we will nee exceptionally to see your actual site because the code you give works perfectly OK as long as that variable is defined in the right place. My suspicion is that on the page where it is not working for you it is not being set with the right scope.

Comment: We have two files index.html (our main code) and index.scss (our main CSS).  Nothing more. If it would be different scope then Chrome should also have the same error but on Chrome, the color is changing properly. The problem is this part `scrollbar-color: var(--sb-bgc) transparent;`. If I put here some color like `#2ac6c7` or `$darkBlueColor` it will show this color properly (it proves that the scope is good and that it is working). I don't understand why `var` is not working.

Comment: Yes, I understand that FF works if you give color a value like red directly,  but it’s the scope of the var that I’m thinking about.

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you mean where `var` is in the stylingsheet? If you mean that, all styling is in one file as I put it in the EDIT code section. We have variable `$lightBlueColor` which we use in `data-theme` for variable `--sb-bgc`. Then we use it in `scrollbar-color` which is in `*` in the same file. Don't know how to explain it further.

Comment: As your code works fine for me on Firefox I think I’d need to see your actual homepage or you need to work on creating a runnable snippet which shows the problem. We can’t debug something that appears to have no bugs!

Answer (score 0):

Firefox use diffrent properties for scrollbar stylings you can add

```
.container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 500px;
  
  **scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: #e3e3e3 transparent;**
}
```

for styling this

for example you can check this link
https://codepen.io/reacraf/pen/ExaBZzZ

Comment: Please read my message again with understanding. I have no problem with the scrollbar when I use a color or a variable directly. I have a problem when I use var(...). And that's only on the home page, if the scrollbar appears on the page somewhere else, for example in the dropdown, then everything is displayed normally. I would like to know why var(...) doesn't only work on the home page.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look at the **browser compatibility** section on the scrollbar styling page on Mozilla's site.

Currently only **Firefox** scrollbar feature:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars

Style the scrollbar for **Chrome and other browsers**:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar
- https://webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox only */
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
}

html,
body {
  block-size: 300%;
}

/* Chrome, Edge, Safari... */
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  background: #5f13ca;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #3b82f6;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #a1a1aa;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: white;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:end:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:start:increment,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:end:decrement {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  block-size: 50vh;
  background-color: #ffecaf;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container > .child {
  background-color: aquamarine;
  inline-size: 50%;
  min-block-size: 300%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="child">
                Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque
                molestias incidunt minus ea praesentium repellendus cum officia
                quas eius quasi distinctio libero non neque id quis inventore
                veritatis nemo, numquam nobis et voluptas voluptatum! Neque,
                blanditiis! Dolores vitae architecto ullam accusamus voluptatem
                ratione ab sit quae quaerat exercitationem fugiat sunt
                laboriosam cupiditate minus omnis labore, facilis sed ut!
                Possimus atque non nobis facilis numquam deleniti officiis
                accusamus consequuntur nisi repudiandae. Veniam, molestias illum
                saepe rerum fuga sapiente dolorum cupiditate pariatur porro ipsa
                blanditiis repudiandae illo eligendi, tempora esse, placeat
                officiis. Facilis, quasi. Facilis inventore hic, vel sint a
                fugit nesciunt.
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

## EDIT:

I edited the code on *Firefox* and realized that; If **HTML** and **BODY** elements are the same size, **HTML**'s scrollbar is valid. Therefore, you can place the attribute named "data-theme" in **HTML** or reduce the width of **BODY** and add a scrollbar to **BODY**.

*only firefox:*

```css
html,
body {
  block-size: 200vh;
}

/* In case you want to add scrollbars to *HTML* and *BODY* elements separately.

html {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
}
body {
    overflow: auto;
    background: rgba(240, 255, 157, 0.5);
    inline-size: 50%;
    block-size: 500px;
}

*/
[data-theme=light] {
  --sb-bgc: red;
}

[data-theme=dark] {
  --sb-bgc: blue;
}

* {
  scrollbar-color: var(--sb-bgc) transparent;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

.scrollable {
  overflow-y: auto;
  inline-size: min(300px, 50%);
  block-size: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Porro
            labore animi officia, ipsam doloribus atque quis cupiditate sequi
            omnis explicabo unde autem culpa, ratione quisquam odit placeat
            veniam debitis, saepe temporibus? Sequi, aperiam modi excepturi
            itaque, facilis exercitationem, consequuntur quidem obcaecati cumque
            aut aspernatur esse quibusdam. Ipsam officia incidunt numquam
            accusamus architecto maxime error labore a suscipit ipsa reiciendis
            cum sunt voluptas adipisci rerum placeat minima molestias amet
            dolorum nihil, possimus nam! Nesciunt perspiciatis, magni eum iure
            dolor, harum sed, recusandae placeat quam aspernatur dolorem.
            Debitis dolore laborum repellat cum non, fuga quibusdam animi
            accusantium tempore nisi maxime repudiandae esse sed perspiciatis
            quas minima reiciendis? Architecto nisi laborum inventore
            perferendis iure repellat officia possimus quisquam, eveniet beatae
            tenetur illum nostrum cum alias, vitae dolores earum, ut quaerat
            error. Repellendus iure impedit inventore a nobis optio, voluptatum
            excepturi dolorem illo earum iste accusantium quae numquam quis
            eaque consequatur soluta? Recusandae dolore iste, nihil porro alias
            esse earum libero suscipit accusantium consequuntur nobis deserunt
            necessitatibus quos facere doloribus vitae, tempore enim culpa
            officiis magni fuga placeat vero? Ratione ex quo quod exercitationem
            quae nesciunt molestiae delectus aperiam magnam aliquam inventore,
            tempora cum blanditiis deleniti id quibusdam possimus recusandae
            accusantium nostrum eum alias libero incidunt nisi! Earum delectus
            itaque deleniti perferendis, ullam nam recusandae, odio repellendus
            repellat, suscipit laudantium voluptate id facere necessitatibus
            distinctio explicabo quibusdam eos doloremque error qui sed officia
            ratione dicta consectetur! Esse vero qui doloremque explicabo dicta
            tempora delectus sapiente, corporis ab ipsam optio perferendis eius
            dolorum. Libero vel sed ad impedit aspernatur maxime nostrum
            repellat possimus dolorem ipsam exercitationem praesentium in, neque
            sit molestiae obcaecati ullam ipsa ratione. Commodi ipsum deserunt
            quisquam suscipit adipisci accusamus! Assumenda eius nesciunt error
            adipisci ad id minus consequuntur, sed eveniet, perferendis a quos
            illum necessitatibus fuga eum dolores harum at. Sint deserunt quae
            doloremque obcaecati? Tempore, necessitatibus hic modi, minus sed
            atque voluptatibus alias assumenda dicta blanditiis porro qui
            reiciendis est. Provident ea odio nihil eligendi ad facere quas quis
            animi suscipit hic dicta enim rem, a laboriosam dolorem culpa
            placeat, delectus, corrupti aliquid! Accusamus nisi vitae
            dignissimos cum praesentium nemo velit, nostrum enim voluptate,
            mollitia voluptatibus repellendus necessitatibus. Earum dolorum
            quasi maiores aliquam aspernatur facere recusandae, fugit
            reprehenderit obcaecati laboriosam totam placeat a? Dolorem nobis
            ratione quos provident! Rem reprehenderit velit est ullam expedita,
            repellat dicta adipisci id alias? Tenetur amet soluta officia eos
            neque repudiandae ullam aliquid unde quasi quibusdam dolore, itaque
            qui nulla deserunt voluptas alias sapiente odit quisquam accusamus
            quae rerum cumque sint quos nisi! Necessitatibus cum neque harum
            sapiente labore tenetur exercitationem, ad magni eveniet maiores
            praesentium dolores ratione dicta soluta consequatur dolorem alias
            quos sed. Veritatis adipisci, nihil accusamus nostrum eaque
            voluptatum aspernatur quaerat voluptate nisi nobis dolores illo
            laboriosam ducimus quas facilis minima nesciunt ipsum. Repudiandae
            amet veritatis est, illum expedita deserunt dicta, provident,
            impedit deleniti possimus vel molestiae facilis explicabo atque.
            Consectetur excepturi porro rem consequatur sequi quod atque
            repellat unde quis recusandae harum earum incidunt soluta aut
            ducimus modi illo esse, dolor repellendus?
        </p>
        <div class="scrollable" data-theme="dark">
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Corporis
            nesciunt accusamus consequatur similique adipisci iusto tempore
            aliquam sapiente esse perferendis deserunt minus modi placeat id
            dolor, ut fuga? Hic, illum id! Laboriosam quaerat numquam ipsum iste
            repellat nam obcaecati possimus, explicabo odio sed impedit vero
            exercitationem quae animi veritatis dignissimos non quam
            praesentium! Eveniet obcaecati ea ad exercitationem quia aperiam
            aliquam fuga ullam maiores dicta laboriosam temporibus vitae alias
            incidunt unde nobis sint, eligendi, recusandae debitis perspiciatis
            voluptatibus magnam odio? Amet accusantium est quisquam sed aut
            saepe, esse perferendis vitae minima necessitatibus, a, doloremque
            earum repellat nulla error labore vero laborum beatae provident
            incidunt neque. Provident, aperiam. Recusandae ipsum maiores
            explicabo nihil, eius quaerat assumenda molestiae reprehenderit
            laboriosam neque odit nemo asperiores totam repudiandae corrupti
            natus obcaecati alias adipisci animi praesentium fugit quisquam cum
            blanditiis eaque. Voluptate tempora magni, dicta maiores similique
            aperiam dolorum totam soluta placeat consectetur commodi? Quos sed,
            esse ea voluptatibus fugiat recusandae? Nam harum consequuntur
            quisquam iusto itaque, molestiae exercitationem distinctio animi
            ratione earum voluptatibus iste ab modi. Laudantium, repudiandae.
            Perspiciatis ut voluptatem laborum nemo voluptas repellendus
            necessitatibus, autem iusto dolor vel inventore ex quae facere
            nulla, reiciendis temporibus facilis provident. Animi, illum
            distinctio non quae ea a incidunt numquam, odio quo dolorum ipsa
            vero ut praesentium deleniti, nisi voluptas! Deleniti voluptate
            alias, repudiandae quod aperiam quasi ad? Fuga iusto consequuntur
            architecto necessitatibus aliquid sed perspiciatis ullam veniam
            reprehenderit sunt accusantium velit commodi officiis adipisci at
            quas nihil quia sit nobis, veritatis eos et illum placeat ex. Alias
            voluptatibus pariatur distinctio illo omnis ex fugit aut aliquid
            animi. Veniam eveniet aperiam omnis amet adipisci hic, esse
            doloribus, velit neque sequi cupiditate ea dicta architecto officia?
            Autem, voluptatem tenetur aspernatur accusantium dolores deserunt
            eius illum saepe ab id veniam deleniti neque corporis voluptate qui
            cum eaque similique tempore voluptas sed iure modi perspiciatis ut!
            Eaque vero voluptas repellendus facere, sint autem maxime unde
            adipisci, numquam cumque accusantium fugit eligendi quam quidem
            optio harum officiis consequatur porro natus, explicabo dolor
            officia ipsam fugiat quaerat? Quod labore non itaque minus veniam
            quam suscipit officia, praesentium asperiores! Unde nulla molestiae
            consectetur sed cupiditate sit et minima, dignissimos quisquam esse
            ipsam voluptatem optio vel eos. Maiores rerum nulla libero fugit
            iure quidem neque, exercitationem tenetur eum natus aliquid
            perferendis id corrupti veritatis inventore quibusdam nostrum
            facilis voluptatum! Reprehenderit quam ipsam voluptatem quasi velit
            dolore quod doloribus nihil, quis iusto veritatis deserunt laborum
            voluptate ut excepturi alias consectetur? Iste delectus, neque
            reiciendis est ipsam ullam at excepturi cupiditate harum deserunt
            dolores illum alias, sed rerum quod corrupti quo possimus nulla
            voluptate voluptas, officia eos vitae. Facere asperiores assumenda
            voluptates aliquid. Laboriosam unde minus praesentium, corporis
            animi esse repellendus mollitia iusto corrupti eum illum minima
            accusamus at quia eos aliquam! Eum aperiam placeat temporibus quia,
            nulla laborum, natus sed tempora consequuntur qui veniam. Nisi
            ratione laudantium, maiores aliquid officiis magni! Facere nulla
            fugit officiis aliquam provident neque ullam similique consequuntur
            autem culpa! At repudiandae excepturi veniam aut nam facilis
            voluptatum, quos nisi. Minus.
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please read my message again with understanding. I have no problem with the scrollbar when I use a color or a variable directly. I have a problem when I use var(...). And that's only on the home page, if the scrollbar appears on the page somewhere else, for example in the dropdown, then everything is displayed normally. I would like to know why var(...) doesn't only work on the home page.

Comment: @Bart If there is a problem, you can write again. I will help as much as I can. 

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently testing this also with Windows 10 and Firefox 109.0.
For me this is working perfectly:

```
scrollbar-width: thin;
scrollbar-color: var(--lpClose) transparent;
scrollbar-color: var(--lpClose) var(--someAnotherVarHere); // This also works nicely
```

My best guess - Maybe there was a bug in an earlier Firefox version.
I cannot find any references to such a bug, though.